# C# class inherrit from derived or base version of class

Tags: c#

Given the example below, is it possible to extend class Foo with ClassyFoo and have Bar instances created by ClassyFoo inherrit from ClassyFoo while maintaining that Bar instances created by Foo still inherit from Foo?

For example:

```
    class Foo
    {
        protected Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up Foo");
        }

        public static void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Showing Foo");
            var bar = new Bar();
        }
    }

    class ClassyFoo : Foo
    {
        public ClassyFoo() : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up Classy Foo");
        }

        public new static void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Showing Classy Foo");
            var bar = new Bar();
        }
    }

    class Bar: Foo
    {
        public Bar() : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up Bar");
        }
    }
```

The desired output of ClassyFoo.Show() being:

> Showing Classy Foo
>   Setting up Foo
>   Setting up Classy Foo
>   Setting up Bar

And the output of Foo.Show() being:

> Showing Foo
>   Setting up Foo
>   Setting up Bar

The situation is class Bar adds some configuration/specialization to Foo, but so does Classy Foo. But both Bar and ClassyFoo's specialization can exist on the same object.

I'm trying to avoid having a duplicate Bar that inherits from ClassyFoo. In reality there are multiple Bars but just one ClassyFoo, so that would be a lot of duplication.

Comment: Instances do not inherit from classes, instances are instances of classes which inherit from other classes. You have `Bar : Foo`, so that is true for all instances of `Bar`. Sounds like you maybe need another subclass, `ClassyBar`.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this approach of creating a Mixin in C# : http://www.zorched.net/2008/01/03/implementing-mixins-with-c-extension-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that is not possible. One class has exactly one base class.

You might be able to implement ClassyFoo and/or Bar as Interfaces and let the actual classes inherit from one, or the other, or both.

Depending on the actual representations and code reuse I'd make both interfaces (similar handling) or one an abstract class (you can stuff a bunch of code in there)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you call to Foo.Show() that is refering instance of Bar has got nothing to do with ClassyFoo si in no way you can expect anything from there.

Comment: Yeah, the hope was there was a way to modify Bar's definition so that there was a tie to both Foo and ClassyFoo through generics or something else I don't know enough about. But it's sounding like not.

Answer (score 0):

as C# does not support Multiple Inheritance you have to use interface for that,without use of interface you cann't do that.